# Sort cells that have the same date but different time

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I currently have a large data set sorted largest to smallest in terms of `demand-(solar+wind)` and I would like to choose the top 12 cells in terms of demand-(solar+wind) but occuring 12 different days.

This is the top of my spreadsheet.

[image]

Thus as the peak `demand-(solar+wind)`often occurs on the same days at different times I have to manually scroll through the large excel file to choose the top 12 that occur on **different** days.

What is a shortcut way to do this? I have thought of conditional formatting or the sort function but none of these have proven useful to me just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply insert a new pivot table, select "Trading interval" as a rows field and demand-(solar+wind) as values.  In your new pivot table right-click on the Trading interval field and select "Group" and "Days".

[image]

Comment: @newtoR, it does not if you set the `value field setting` / `summurize value field by` and chose `MAX` and not `SUM`